# how can I stop my contacts being listed twice?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have a sample app where the contacts in my android phone are listed and I can search for them. However, very often the contacts are listed twice. I only want them to be listed once. What should I change in my code to fix this? I've posted the relevant parts of my code below.

I did try here [how to remove duplicate contacts from arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959625/how-to-remove-duplicate-contacts-from-arraylist) but I couldn't modify the code sufficiently to suit my needs.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.chris.contactlistcustomlistview;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.ContentResolver;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.provider.ContactsContract;
        import android.provider.MediaStore;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.SearchView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // ArrayList
    ArrayList<SelectUser> selectUsers;
    List<SelectUser> temp;
    // Contact List
    ListView listView;

    // Cursor to load contacts list
    Cursor phones, email;

    // Pop up
    ContentResolver resolver;
    SearchView search;
    SelectUserAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        selectUsers = new ArrayList<SelectUser>();
        resolver = this.getContentResolver();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);

        phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
//        retrieves contact information
        LoadContact loadContact = new LoadContact();
        loadContact.execute();

//        let's set up our search box,
        search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);

        //*** setOnQueryTextListener ***
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // when the text in searchView changes, call the filter function
                adapter.filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    // Load data on background
    class LoadContact extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            // Get Contact list from Phone


            if (phones != null) {
                Log.e("count", "" + phones.getCount());
                if (phones.getCount() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No contacts in your contact list.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    Bitmap bit_thumb = null;
                    String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                    String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String EmailAddr = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA2));
                    String image_thumb = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));
                    try {
                        if (image_thumb != null) {
                            bit_thumb = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(resolver, Uri.parse(image_thumb));
                        } else {
                            Log.e("No Image Thumb", "--------------");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
//what's happening here? For every user in the phonebook, show an image, the name, number, an id and maybe a checkbox?
                    SelectUser selectUser = new SelectUser();
                    selectUser.setThumb(bit_thumb);
                    selectUser.setName(name);
                    selectUser.setPhone(phoneNumber);
                    selectUser.setEmail(id);
                    selectUser.setCheckedBox(false);
                    selectUsers.add(selectUser);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Cursor close 1", "----------------");
            }
            //phones.close();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
//        when DoInBackground is finished, when we have our phone number, name etc... display the results in our listview.
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            adapter = new SelectUserAdapter(selectUsers, MainActivity.this);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Select item on listclick
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    Log.e("search", "here---------------- listener");

                    SelectUser data = selectUsers.get(i);
                }
            });

            listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        phones.close();
    }
}
```

**SelectUserAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.chris.contactlistcustomlistview;

        import android.annotation.TargetApi;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
        import android.os.Build;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
        import android.widget.CheckBox;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Chris on 25/03/2016.
 */

public class SelectUserAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public List<SelectUser> _data;
    private ArrayList<SelectUser> arraylist;
    Context _c;
    ViewHolder v;
//    RoundImage roundedImage;

    public SelectUserAdapter(List<SelectUser> selectUsers, Context context) {
        _data = selectUsers;
        _c = context;
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<SelectUser>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(_data);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return _data.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = li.inflate(R.layout.inflate_listview, null);
            Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view1");
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            Log.e("Inside", "here--------------------------- In view2");
        }

//        we are making a cell format in the ListView, which will contain info like
//        number, name... the layout for this, with name, no, pic etc...
//        is contained in inflate_listview.xml, which describes how each cell data
//        loads into the listview
        v = new ViewHolder();

//      So, for example, title is cast to the name id, in activity main,
//        phone is cast to the id called no etc
        v.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        v.check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        v.phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.no);
//        v.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pic);

//        for each new cell with title, name, number etc...
//
        final SelectUser data = (SelectUser) _data.get(i);
        v.title.setText(data.getName());
        v.check.setChecked(data.getCheckedBox());
        v.phone.setText(data.getPhone());



        Log.e("Image Thumb", "--------------" + data.getThumb());

        view.setTag(data);
        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
//        _data is our list of Users, or contacts
        _data.clear();
//        If there is nothing in the searchbox,
//        then show all the contacts
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            _data.addAll(arraylist);
//            or else....
        } else {
            for (SelectUser wp : arraylist) {
//                If a contact's phone number matches the input thus far that the user
//                is filtering for, then include it in the listview.
                if (wp.getPhone().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    _data.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    static class ViewHolder {
//        In each cell in the listview show a name and phone number
//        ImageView imageView;
        TextView title, phone;
        CheckBox check;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are they duplicated in your list or in your adapter?

Comment: When I try the app on my phone, I can see lots of the contacts are listed twice, one immediately after the other. So I guess that would mean they're duplicated in my list.

Comment: Don't guess, debug so we can locate the problem. I've had trouble with items being shown once in the List and multiple times in the Listview which used some Adapter. Tell me when you locate the problem. Btw are you getting the contacts from your phone? I have multiple contacts there, one in phone memory, one in SIM card.

Comment: Yes, from my phone. The stock android app just shows the contact once, which is what I want my one to do. Will look it up when home and let you know, thanks.

Comment: No problem bro, try debugging always and locating the **exact** place of your error. It's easier for us to help you that way. You can easily test my theory about contacts by looking at your **Contacts** and seeing which ones you have in `BOTH` your phone and your SIM card, and comparing if they're the ones duplicating in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    Cursor cursor;
    ListView mainListView;
    ArrayList hashMapsArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();}
        try {

            cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
                    .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            int Idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID);
            int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

            int phoneNumberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            int photoIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI);
            cursor.moveToFirst();


            Set<String> ids = new HashSet<>();
            do {
                System.out.println("=====>in while");
                String contactid=cursor.getString(Idx);
                if (!ids.contains(contactid)) {
                    ids.add(contactid);
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                   String  name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
                    String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneNumberIdx);
                    String image = cursor.getString(photoIdIdx);
                    System.out.println("Id--->"+contactid+"Name--->"+name);
                    System.out.println("Id--->"+contactid+"Number--->"+phoneNumber);

                    if (!phoneNumber.contains("*")) {
                        hashMap.put("contactid", "" + contactid);
                        hashMap.put("name", "" + name);
                        hashMap.put("phoneNumber", "" + phoneNumber);
                        hashMap.put("image", "" + image);
                        // hashMap.put("email", ""+email);
                        if (hashMapsArrayList != null) {
                            hashMapsArrayList.add(hashMap);}
//                    hashMapsArrayList.add(hashMap);
                    }
                }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am not sure it will solve this problem.

```
 if (selectUsers.indexOf(selectUser) == -1) {
     selectUsers.add(selectUser);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it when I'm home. And would you put this in the filter method?

Comment: No, in doInBackground method. I guess this is the correct place.